# How can I make js objects' content be pulled in from an html file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, object

I have a few js objects containing data that I would like to make it so that the owner can modify from an html file.

In other words, the js object lives in its own js file, but I'm afraid the person editing the data in objects may delete/update the actual code...basically I would like to make it idiot proof. So I'm thinking of having the data live in an html file or even a .txt file to make editing super easy.

Basically anything like A1, A2, A3, A4, B1, B2, etc etc etc... I would like those to live in a separate file in the simplest way possible. Any ideas?

Here is a sample of the objects I have:

```js
var objOne = [
  {first: 'A1', second: 'A2', third: 'A3', fourth: 'A4'},
  {first: 'B1', second: 'B2', third: 'B3', fourth: 'B4'},
  {first: 'C1', second: 'C2', third: 'C3', fourth: 'C4'}
];


var objTwo = [
  {first: 'D1', second: 'D2', third: 'D3', fourth: 'D4'},
  {first: 'E1', second: 'E2', third: 'E3', fourth: 'E4'},
  {first: 'F1', second: 'F2', third: 'F3', fourth: 'F4'}
];


$('.div span').html( objOne[0].fourth + ' >> ' + objTwo[2].third);
```

```html
<div class="div">Element: <span></span></div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Thank you all.

Sergio

Comment: why not a JSON file?

Comment: I could, but I'm just afraid that a quotation or a comaa will be deleted, or a curly bracket omitted... I really would like (and I'm not sure if this is possible) something like this: - first A1 - second A2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's what jquery is for. You can load a plain text file

```
$.get('/path/to/file.txt', function(response) {
    var data = response;
}, 'text');
```

and then parse it in the browser, and insert the result into your HTML. Or you could use Markdown in you user-modified file

```
$.get('/path/to/file.md', function(response) {
    var data = response;
    var converter = new Showdown.converter();
    var html = converter.makeHtml(data);
    $('.content').html(html);
}, 'text');
```

and then use a Javascript markdown library (for example [Showdown](https://github.com/showdownjs/showdown)) to convert it to HTML in the browser.

There are libraries for a number of data formats, to parse them directly in the browser and then insert the ready-made HTML into your page.

Comment: I'm not sure Im following you, well I am, but how would the .txt file look like with the data for the objects?

Comment: For the data in your examples you can use JSON files, that's simple text files in the form of JS Object Notation. So, your file would be `[{first: 'A1', second: 'A2', third: 'A3', fourth: 'A4'}, ...]` and you can load it with `$.get('file.json', callback, 'json')`. The callback function then gets a regular Javascript object from jquery.

Comment: Yeah, but as I mentioned on Gerardo's comment, I'm afraid that a quotation or a comma will be deleted, or a curly bracket omitted... I really would like (and I'm not sure if this is possible) something like this: - first A1 - second A2.... in its simplest form possible. I know I can integrate a db table to do this, but I don't think for its needs a db table is really necessary.

Comment: That's what I thought. So, a more "free" format like Markdown, CSV /  TabSeperatedValues, ReStructuredText, etc would probably be better. There are JS libraries to parse any of those.

Comment: I found a CSV parser...I will go that route. Thank you.